# Does filamentphp update in live time?

Tags: laravel, laravel-echo, laravel-filament, filamentphp

I'm trying to build a simple dashboard with filamentphp, and I wonder if I have 2 logged in sessions, and I tried updating the table https://demo.filamentphp.com/ and if I update it in one window, the update isn't reflected in the other window.

Is filament even cable of such thing? It looks like it does laravel/echo under the hood.

Comment: No not by default, the only thing Filament supports is broadcasting notifications, and polling on widgets/forms/tables. So if you want a reactive table you should implement it yourself